# Actionscript3 Simple platform collision confusion

Tags: actionscript-3, collision-detection, flashdevelop

I'm making a 2D platformer game and i'm trying to add collisions to the platforms so that when the character hits it it cannot pass through. I'm struggling to find the syntax to use to create this collision. So far this is what I have.

Also i would still like to be able to use hitTestObject within the if statement.

thanks

```
public function platform1Collision():void
    {
        if (fireboy1.hitTestObject(Platform1))
        {
            //fireboy1 cannot pass through

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably want to prevent `fireboy1`'s `y` property from extending past `Platform1`'s `y` property:

```
function platform1Collision():void
{
    if(fireboy1.hitTestObject(Platform1))
    {
        if(fireboy1.y > Platform1.y)
        {
            fireboy1.y = Platform1.y + Platform1.height;
        }
        else
        {
            fireboy1.y = Platform1.y - fireboy1.height;
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** The above code sample assumes top-left orientation for both `fireboy1` and `Platform1`.

**EDITED**: The above edited code will allow `fireboy1` to walk beneath `Platform1`, but not pass through it.

This is a very rudimentary example to give you an idea of the type of logic you can use. If you want to allow `fireboy1` to pass through `Platform1` from below, you'll have to update the logic to allow for that. For example, if you take out the `if/else` and just automatically place `fireboy1` above `Platform1` every time they collide, it will appear as if `player1` is jumping onto `Platform1` when it is approached from below.

Comment: this doesn't work if I want to go back down beneath the position of Platform1 though.

Comment: Also I want to have it still using hitTestObject

Comment: There are many ways to go about this (probably why someone already voted to have this question closed due to being "too broad"). I believe I've now given you more than enough to go on. If you are still struggling, post more of the code that you've already attempted.